# not found my xml with codeigniter?

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

I get this message that tell that the xml was not found but then I get product ID, product name, I dont figure out how can I fix that, please help me

/* End of file welcome.php */ /* Location: ./system/application/controllers/welcome.php */ File“C:\Users\amaury\Documents\xml\myxml.xmlwas not found
  PRODUCT ID   PRODUCT NAME   CATEGORY   PRICE

This is my code:

```
function _getXML($fname)
{
    $filename = $fname.'.xml';
    $xmlfile="“C:\\Users\\beto\\Documents\\xml\\".$filename;
    //$xmlRaw = file_get_contents($xmlfile);
    $result = '';

    //$this->load->library('simplexml');
    //$xmlData = $this->simplexml->xml_parse($xmlRaw);

    if(file_exists($xmlfile)){
        $xmlRaw = file_get_contents($xmlfile);
        $this->load->library('simplexml');
        $xmlData = $this->simplexml->xml_parse($xmlRaw);
        foreach($xmlData['Emisor'] as $row)
        {
            $result .= '<tr>';
            $result .= '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
            $result .= '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
            $result .= '<td>'.$row['category'].'</td>';
            $result .= '<td>$ '.$row['price'].'</td>';
            $result .= '</tr>';
        }
    }else{
        $result = 'File' . $xmlfile . 'was not found';
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have an extra set of curly quotes in your path. 
`"“C:\\`

Is that in your actual code? It might be the cause of your issue.

`“C:\\Users\\beto\\Documents\\xml\\myxml.xml` won't exist, but `C:\\Users\\beto\\Documents\\xml\\myxml.xml` will.

Comment: even if I change the directory I get the same result  $xmlfile="“C:\Users\beto\Documents\xml\myxml.xml".$filename;

Comment: @George try changing the line to `$xmlfile="C:\\Users\\beto\\Documents\\xml\\myxml.xml";`

Comment: @Mark E thanks por answering but I already change it, and I get the same error

Comment: @GeorgeBecj - Have you confirmed that the file does indeed exist on the filesystem, even copy/paste the path returned in the error to ensure there isn't a cAsE sEnSiTivIty issue with the path?